# Counting Circular Sequence (Burnside Lemma?)

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

1. How many distinct circular binary sequences of length $n$ are there?
2. How many distinct circular binary sequences of length $n$ containing a given pattern, e.g., $110$ are there?
3. The same questions as in Question 1. and 2. for circular sequence of elements from $\{1,2,...,k\}$.

Do we need the [Burnside orbit counting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma)?

Comment: These are called [necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29), and yes, they can be counted using the Burnside lemma. Question $2$ seems difficult.

Comment: @joriki: Thank you for providing the solution and confirming my hunch. Please let me know if you have any leads to Question 2.

Comment: For Question 2, you could look into [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), but the interaction between the pattern constraints and the periodicity condition seems daunting.

Comment: @joriki I upvoted your observation, which I certainly agree with. Moreover when you compute the necklaces containing the pattern 110 you get a sequence that does not have an OEIS entry. Given the simplicity of the problem statement that fact suggests it being a challenging problem. Burnside has no notion of adjacency.

Comment: Apparently the sequence is $$0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 14, 27, 49, 92, 168, 320, 590, 1117,\ldots$$ and the complementary sequence is $$2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 9, 11, 16, 20, 32, 42, 65,\ldots$$ and these add to $$2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 14, 20, 36, 60, 108, 188, 352, 632, 1182,\ldots$$ which is [OEIS A000031](https://oeis.org/A000031).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now  treat the  case of an  alphabet of  $k$ letters rather  than a
binary  alphabet. We  use two  classes of  letters, the  pattern being
represented by  $WWY_0$ and an  additional sequence of  letters from
$Y_1$ to $Y_{k-2}.$ In this way we obtain $k$ letters total.

Now there are several cases, the easiest is if $W$ does not ocur at
all. These are given by

$$Q_{n, k-1} = 
Z(C_n)(Y_0+Y_1+\cdots+Y_{k-2})_{Y_0=Y_1=\cdot=Y_{k-2}=1}.$$

This quantity can also be  computed by Burnside, I chose Polya because
the code for it was already written.

The second case is a  necklace consisting of instances of $W$ only,
of which there is exactly one.

The third case is a necklace of blocks starting with an initial run
of ones of some length  followed by other letters. The key observation
here is  that any  rotational symmetry  must map the  runs of  ones to
themselves,  so the  symmetry  of blocks  corresponds  exactly to  the
symmetry of  single letters. That  means we may consider  necklaces of
blocks instead of necklaces of letters.

We must now  construct the inventory of blocks for  use with Redfield-Polya Enumeration Theorem. A
block starts with a run of ones  but a run of a single one is special,
in that it may be followed by any letter whereas a run of at least two
ones  may not  be followed  by $Y_0.$  We make  a design  choice here,
marking  all  letters  with  a  $Z$  so  that  the  desired  count  is
coefficient on $[Z^n].$  We will show later how  the  variables  other 
than $Z$  can  be  optimized out.  We  thus get  for the inventory  of 
blocks

$$WZ\sum_{q=1}^n (ZY_0+\cdots+ZY_{k-2})^q
\\ + \sum_{p=2}^n W^pZ^p (ZY_1+\cdots+ZY_{k-2}) 
\sum_{q=0}^n (ZY_0+\cdots+ZY_{k-2})^q.$$

We may form necklaces of one block, two and so on to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ of
these blocks. We therefore get the formula

$$1 + Q_{n,k-1} +
\sum_{s=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
[Z^n] Z(C_s)
\left(WZ\sum_{q=1}^n \left(\sum_{r=0}^{k-2} ZY_r\right)^q
\\ + \sum_{p=2}^n W^p Z^p \sum_{r=1}^{k-2} ZY_r
\sum_{q=0}^n \left(\sum_{r=0}^{k-2} ZY_r\right)^q
\right)_{W=Y_0=\cdots=Y_{k-2}=1}.$$

Observe that  the $Z(C_s)$ refers  to the cycle  index and not  to the
variable $Z$, which  counts the total letters in  the necklace. We now
optimize  this   formula  as  promised  and   improve  readablity  and
efficiency. Making the substitutions we get

$$1 + Q_{n,k-1}
\\ +\sum_{s=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
[z^n] Z(C_s)
\left(z\sum_{q=1}^n (k-1)^q z^q
+ \sum_{p=2}^n z^p (k-2) z
\sum_{q=0}^n (k-1)^q z^q\right).$$

Clearly additional simplification is possible  here as the sums have a
closed form but the  resulting expression does not necessarily provide
a gain in insight or compactness.

With  this formula in  place we  can start  to compute  counts. The
binary case is the same as in the companion post.

For three letters we get

$$3, 6, 10, 21, 42, 103, 237, 603, 1519, 3942, 10257, 27131, 71940,
\\ 192462, 516933, 1395636, 3781356, 10283911, 28050600, 76732047,
\\ 210414811, 578330649,\ldots$$

for four letters

$$4, 10, 23, 66, 192, 636, 2092, 7228, 25175, 89212, 318808, 1150444, 
\\ 4177908,  15268494, 56078527, 206903020, 766342160, 2848351388, 
\\ 10619472284, 39702648534,\ldots$$

and for five letters

$$5, 15, 44, 160, 604, 2510, 10545, 45825, 201669, 900307, 4057625, 
\\ 18447565, 84444000, 388878560, 1799985435, 8368841895, 39062428790, 
\\ 182961584260,\ldots$$

The Maple code for this was as follows.

```
with(numtheory);

Y :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local d, dd, ind, orbit, orbits, pos, shft;

    if k = 1 then return 1 fi;

    orbits := {};

    for ind from k^n to 2*k^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, k);

        dd := [seq(d[q], q=1..n), d[1], d[2]];

        for pos to n do
            if dd[pos] = 1 and
            dd[pos+1] = 1 and dd[pos+2] = 0 then
                break;
            fi;
        od;

        if pos = n+1 then
            orbit := {};

            for shft to n do
                orbit :=
                {op(orbit),
                 [seq(d[p], p=shft .. n),
                  seq(d[p], p=1..shft-1)]};
            od;

            orbits := {op(orbits), orbit};
        fi;
    od;

    nops(orbits);
end;


pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
proc(n)
local d, s;

    s := 0;
    for d in divisors(n) do
        s := s + phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d);
    od;

    s/n;
end;

pet_cycleind_cyclic_num :=
proc(n, k)
local d, s;

    s := 0;
    for d in divisors(n) do
        s := s + phi(d)*k^(n/d);
    od;

    s/n;
end;


R :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local res, seg, inv, ovars, ofree, rest, gf;

    if k = 1 then return 1 fi;

    ovars := add(Z*Y[q], q=0..k-2);
    ofree := add(Y[q], q=0..k-2);

    inv := add(W*Z*ovars^q, q=1..n)
    + add(add(W^p*Z^p*(ovars-Z*Y[0])*ovars^q, q=0..n),
          p=2..n);

    res := 0;

    for seg to floor(n/2) do
        gf := expand(pet_varinto_cind
                     (inv, pet_cycleind_cyclic(seg)));
        res := res + coeff(gf, Z, n);
    od;

    rest := pet_varinto_cind(ofree, pet_cycleind_cyclic(n));

    1 + subs({W=1, seq(Y[q]=1, q=0..k-2)}, res + rest);
end;

R2 :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local seg, gf, res;

    if k = 1 then return 1 fi;

    res := 0;

    gf := z*add((k-1)^q*z^q, q=1..n)
    + add(z^p*(k-2)*z*add((k-1)^q*z^q, q=0..n), p=2..n);

    for seg to floor(n/2) do
        res := res +
        coeff(expand(pet_varinto_cind
                     (gf, pet_cycleind_cyclic(seg))),
              z, n);
    od;


    1 + pet_cycleind_cyclic_num(n, k-1) + res;
end;
```

Just to be on the safe side here is another total enumeration routine,
this one written in Perl. It  matches the values from the formula that
are listed above. (Practical to about $n=10.$)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

MAIN : {
    my $mx = shift || 10;
    my $k = shift || 2;

    my @res = ($k);

    for(my $n=2; $n <= $mx; $n++){
        my %orbits;

        for(my $ind = 0; $ind < $k ** $n; $ind++){
            my ($pos, $idx, @d);

            for(($pos, $idx) = (0, $ind); 
                $pos < $n; $pos++){
                my $digit = $idx % $k;

                push @d, $digit;
                $idx = ($idx-$digit) / $k;
            }

            push @d, $d[0], $d[1];

            for($pos=0; $pos < $n; $pos++){
                last if $d[$pos] == 1 && $d[$pos+1] == 1
                    && $d[$pos+2] == 0;
            }

            pop @d; pop @d;

            if($pos == $n){
                my %orbit;
                for(my $shft = 0; $shft < $n; $shft++){
                    my $str =
                        join('-', 
                             @d[$shft..$n-1], @d[0..$shft-1]);
                    $orbit{$str} = 1;
                }

                my $orbstr = join('|', sort(keys %orbit));
                $orbits{$orbstr} = 1;
            }
        }

        push @res, scalar(keys %orbits);
    }

    print join(', ', @res);
    print "\n";

    1;
}
```

Comment: Nice approach! (+1) for both

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you use a programming language when you work on MSE?

Comment: You're welcome! Sometimes I write some R or perl snippets. Most of them for simple verifying tasks.

Comment: Awesome! +1 Thank you, Marko Riedel. I need some time to study your wonderful answer. Also what does PET stand for?

Comment: PET = Polya Enumeration Theorem, this is the version for generating functions of Burnside's lemma.

Comment: @Hans  I prefer that possible edits are discussed in the comments first.

Comment: I am sorry for taking the liberty, Marko. I will do as you prefer next time. In this case, are you alright with expanding the acronym from PET to Redfield-Polya Enumeration Theorem?

Comment: No need to be sorry. I accepted the edit and did not do a rollback.

Answer (score 2):

In the present case (binary necklace, forbidden pattern $110$) we have
a simple observation (which does not generalize). This is if we divide
the necklace  into adjacent segments consisting of  repetitions of one
and the  same symbol we cannot  have a run  of two or more  ones since
these would form the pattern $110$  with the zero following the run of
ones.  Therefore  we are distributing  singleton ones on  the necklace
separated by runs  of zeros. The minimum here is a  single one and the
maximum  is $\lfloor  n/2\rfloor.$  (As the  separating  run of  zeros
contains at least one zero this  is the highest we can get.) With this
observations  we have  reduced  the problem  to  an ordinary  necklace
problem as we now have a necklace of runs of zeros in the slots of the
necklace. We thus  get the formula (using the  cycle index $Z(C_q)$ of
of the cyclic group)

$$2+\sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
[x^{n-q}] Z(C_q)(x+x^2+\cdots+x^n).$$

Here $q$ counts the number of singleton ones, producing the sequence

$$2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 9, 11, 16, 20, 32, 42, 65, 95, 144, 212,
\\  330, 494, 767, 1171, 1812, 2788, 4342, 6714, 10463, 16275,
\\ 25416, 39652, 62076, 97110, 152289,\ldots$$

The two  in front  represents necklaces consisting  of zeros  only and
ones only which do not contain the pattern either.

The Maple code to compute and verify these was as follows.

```
with(numtheory);

Y :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local d, dd, ind, orbit, orbits, pos, shft;

    orbits := {};

    for ind from 2^n to 2*2^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, 2);
        # print([seq(d[p], p=1..n)]);

        dd := [seq(d[q], q=1..n), d[1], d[2]];

        for pos to n do
            if dd[pos] = 1 and
            dd[pos+1] = 1 and dd[pos+2] = 0 then
                break;
            fi;
        od;

        if pos = n+1 then
            orbit := {};

            for shft to n do
                orbit :=
                {op(orbit),
                 [seq(d[p], p=shft .. n),
                  seq(d[p], p=1..shft-1)]};
            od;

            orbits := {op(orbits), orbit};
        fi;
    od;

    nops(orbits);
end;

XY :=
proc(n)
    local d;

    1/n*add(phi(d)*2^(n/d), d in divisors(n));
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
proc(n)
local d, s;

    s := 0;
    for d in divisors(n) do
        s := s + phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d);
    od;

    s/n;
end;

R :=
proc(n)
local res, seg, vars, gf;

    vars := add(X^q, q=1..n);

    res := 0;

    for seg to floor(n/2) do
        gf := expand(pet_varinto_cind
                     (vars, pet_cycleind_cyclic(seg)));
        res := res + coeff(gf, X, n-seg);
    od;

    res+2;
end;
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. It will be great if you would look into a solution for general patterns.

Comment: I believe I have solved this case as well. I need to run a few more checks and then I'll post.

Comment: Excellent! Does that include question 3?

Comment: Yes it does. Be patient.